# Need Help on .htaccess code to redirect dynamic URL into static

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I am new member at this forum but using this site since long back. This time I am looking for custom help on `.htaccess` code to redirect my website URLs into static one. I will appreciate if someone can help on this –

Below is current live link -

http://sitename.in/categories.php?category=chocolate-special&parent_id=12067

Same is going in all categories

I want to convert it into

http://sitename.in/chocolate-special/12067

Currently I am using –

```
RewriteRule ^products/([a-zA-Z0-9-_%/,]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9-_%/,]+)/?$ categories.php?category=$1&parent_id=$2 [L,QSA]
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /categories\.php\?category=([^\s&]+)&parent_id=([^\s&]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ products/%1/%2? [R=301,L]
```

But it’s not helping me at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work for you:

```
RewriteEngine On

# Rewrite products/*/* to categories.php, and send a dummy/useless parameter (r=1)

RewriteRule ^products/([a-zA-Z0-9-_%/,]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9-_%/,]+)/?$ categories.php?category=$1&parent_id=$2&r=1 [NC,QSA,L]

# Check access to the old URL, and redirect to the new URL
# Leave the dummy parameter (r=1) out of this so that there is no endless loop

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^category=([^\s&]+)&parent_id=([\d]+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^categories.php /products/%1/%2? [R=301,L]
```

**Extended:** (for new request in comments)

```
RewriteEngine On

# Rewrite products/*/* to categories.php, and send a dummy/useless parameter (r=1)
RewriteRule ^products/([a-z0-9-_%/,]+)/([a-z0-9-_%/,]+)/?$ categories.php?category=$1&parent_id=$2&r=1 [NC,QSA,L]

# Rewrite auction-details/*/* to auction_details.php, and send a dummy/useless parameter (r=1)
RewriteRule ^auction-details/([a-z0-9-_%/,]+)/([\d]+)/?$ auction_details.php?name=$1&id=$2&r=1 [NC,QSA,L]

# Check access to the old URLs, and redirect to the new URLs
# Leave the dummy parameter (r=1) out of this so that there is no endless loop

# categories.php
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^category=([^\s&]+)&parent_id=([\d]+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^categories.php /products/%1/%2? [R=301,L]

# auction_details.php
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^name=([^\s&]+)&id=([\d]+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^auction_details.php /auction-details/%1/%2? [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Thanks a lot #Mike its working accurately for category URLs... May you please check below product URL and give some redirection suggestion for this too. 

http://websitename.in/auction_details.php?name=any-products-name_id=139955

Should be 
http://websitename.in/category-name/any-products-name/139955

Comment: You're welcome. You don't want to pass the `category-name` to the `auction_details.php` script?

Comment: No I dont want because auction_details.php in every products URLs looking unnecessary and should be redirect to a good readable URL

Comment: The problem is that if you input `/auction_details.php?name=any-products-name_id=139955`, there is no way to guess the `category-name`, and so you would not be able to redirect to `/category-name/any-products-name/139955`. However, you can redirect to `/auction-details/any-products-name/139955`.

Comment: Okay.. May you please suggest me redirection code for -- /auction-details/any-products-name/139955

Comment: Answer updated. Please try and learn from the examples for any other redirects you may wish to do in the future. If you have trouble with them, feel free to open a new question as this question has already been answered.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/([^/]*)$ /categories.php?category=$1&parent_id=$2 [L,R=301]
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing but its not helping me as no changes on URL

Comment: Have you enabled RewriteEngine by doing: `RewriteEngine On`?

Comment: @PunitKumar There was an additional backsplash. I fixed it, please try again.

Comment: Still not useful for me